# Equality of two lists of complex numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, complex

I have these two lists of complex numbers:

```
radix = ResourceFunction["ComplexRoots"][I, 6]

solu = SolveValues[z^6 == I, z] // 
  PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> True] &
```

how can I use Mathematica to prove that radix=solu?

Answer (score 6):

```
radix = ResourceFunction["ComplexRoots"][I, 6]

solu = SolveValues[z^6 == I, z] // 
  PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> True] &

Sort@ComplexExpand@radix == Sort@ComplexExpand@solu // Simplify
```

> `True`

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

radix = ResourceFunction["ComplexRoots"][I, 6];

solu = SolveValues[z^6 == I, z] // 
   PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> True] &;

SortBy[radix, N] == SortBy[solu, N]

(* True *)
```